# javascript date conversion showing wrong month

Tags: javascript, date, formatting

In the following date conversion after converting back the long integer The date says october instead of september

```
 var date = 2013-09-23 18:31
 startdate = getTimeStamp(date); //1382533260000
```

Now

```
 t=1382533260000   
 rt = new Date(t)
 //Wed Oct 23 2013 18:31:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)


 function getTimeStamp(strDate) { 
            var a1=strDate.split(" ");
            var d1=a1[0].split("-");
            var t1=a1[1].split(":");
            var dtObj = new Date(d1[0],d1[1],d1[2],t1[0],t1[1]);
            return dtObj.getTime();
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Months are zero-based, so January is zero, February is one, etc..

So you need to use `d1[1]-1` in your `new Date()` constructor.

Comment: Uh? That would subtract one millisecond, how would that help?

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, month numbers are numbered 0-11.

If you're parsing from components like this into the `Date` constructor you'll have to subtract one from the number:

```
 function getTimeStamp(strDate) { 
            var a1=strDate.split(" ");
            var d1=a1[0].split("-");
            var t1=a1[1].split(":");
            var dtObj = new Date(d1[0],d1[1] - 1,d1[2],t1[0],t1[1]);
            return dtObj.getTime();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript month parameter starts from 0 upto 11 so, passing 8 means september