# Why is new Date(2015,01,01) Feb, 01 2015 in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am wondering why the date of the constructor and the printed date is different. It is shown as a month late.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript is creating date wrong month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12254333/javascript-is-creating-date-wrong-month) and http://stackoverflow.com/q/25288781/1612146 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/19244052/1612146 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649036/creating-date-with-numbers-new-date2012-03-gives-wrong-month-1 -- The list goes on.

Comment: Because `Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December.` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See reference: [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```
month
Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11    for December.
```

Answer (score 8):

Month is zero-based in many languages. This means

```
0 -> January
1 -> February
2 -> March
...
```

> **month**
>   Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December.

<sup>Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date</sup>